# Java read .xml with this path: .zip/.ear/directory/.jar/directory/.xml

Tags: java, xml

I have a zip file containing a file within ear. Inside the ear file and a folder within a jar file folder.

Finally, within the jar file is an xml. Read the xml is not a problem, the problem is to get to the xml file without unzipping anything.

I managed to get to the ear file, but nothing else

```
public ZipInputStream inner(ZipFile zf, ZipEntry ze) {
    InputStream innerZipStream;
    ZipInputStream innerZis = null;
    try {
        innerZipStream = zf.getInputStream(ze);
        innerZis = new ZipInputStream(innerZipStream);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Dependencias.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return innerZis;
} public String gEar(ZipFile zip) throws IOException {
    String earName = null;
    extreureDades(zip.getName());
    try {
        ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(ruta + File.separator + zip.getName()));
        ZipEntry entry;

        while (null != (entry = zis.getNextEntry())) {
            System.out.println(entry.getName());
            if (entry.getName().endsWith(".ear")) {
                ZipInputStream zisEar = inner(zip, entry);
                ZipEntry entryEar;
                while (null != (entryEar = zisEar.getNextEntry())) {
                    System.out.println("-----------" + entryEar.getName());
                    if (entryEar.getName().contains("META-INF/")) {

                    } else if (entryEar.getName().contains("lib/")) {

                        if (entryEar.getName().endsWith(".jar")) {
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            zis.closeEntry();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Dependencias.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return earName;
}
```